# Google sheets macro for switching to another sheet based of drop-down selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently building a function where when a certain selection is selected from a drop-down data validation menu, the user is redirected to a different sheet within the workbook. What I currently have does not return an error but also does not do what is intended. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function gotoselectsheetnosheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(4,3);
  var data = range.getValue();  
  if (data == "Answers")
  {  
     var dinner = ss.getSheetByName('Answers');
     dinner.activate();
   }
}
```

[please see this image for further clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAyxe.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Menu" && e.range.getRow() === 4 && e.range.getColumn() === 3) {
    e.source.getSheetByName(e.value).activate();
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")

Comment: Thats because you ran the function manually. It should be called automatically when you change your selection in the drop down list.

Comment: How can I set this up? I just began using google sheets

Comment: You don't need to set this up. It works automatically. If there is a function with the name `onEdit`, it will be called automatically whenever some value in the spreadsheet changes.

Comment: btw. Cooper's solution will work as well. The only real difference is that he used a manually added trigger instead of an automatic one.

Answer (score 1):

This works if you setup an onEdit() trigger.

```
function gotosheet(e)
{
  e.source.getSheetByName(e.value).activate();

}
```

e.source is the event event objects resource for the spreadsheet object. Look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to learn more about it.

So then the next is getSheetByName(e.value) and e.value is the new value in the cell being edited.

Then the next is activate.  And that makes it move to the named sheet.  So presumably you have selected the appropriate sheet names in your validation setup.

Validation setup:

[image]

[image]
When you select one of the two possible selections in the validation drop down that triggers the onEdit trigger and the function takes you to the tab with that name.

Named Range Used in Validation Setup:

[image]

OnEdit Trigger Setup:

[image]

Comment: can you make this into a coherent function because I am having trouble following your logic with the individual code snippets

Comment: so I need two separate functions to do this?

Comment: Is that a question or a statement? I don't understand.

Comment: a question. you created a function with one line so I am not sure how I am supposed to incorporate it into what i have already written

Comment: I'm suggesting that my function replaces all of your code.

Comment: oh i see. so how does your function incorporate my data validation drop-down?

Comment: I have named range "Bull Sheet" which has two names "Dinner" and "Lunch" and I have three sheets Menu, Dinner and Lunch.  I set up the validation column on Menu and I can jump to either Lunch or Dinner.  I also setup an onEdit() trigger to this function because that's how it works.

Comment: I get an error TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")

Comment: I'd guess your trying run it without the event trigger. That won't work because your missing the event object

Comment: And your getting an error when you edit the drop downs?  You have to actually change them.

Comment: if SpiderPigs solution is working for you that's cool with me.  This isn't a competition. I do this because I've been able to learn a lot about Google Apps Script in a short amount of time.  I don't like useing the uninstallable onEdits because they tend to clog up my stackoverflow projects because I forget to change their names.